# RequiresApi not found in android.support.annotation

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-sdk-manager

As https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html says support-annotation.jar contains a method called `RequiresApi`. However, I could not found the method in `android-support-annotations.jar` which 
I download by SDK manager (Android Support Library(23.2.2)).

Answer (score 2):

As you can check in the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RequiresApi.html) and in the source `RequiresApi` **is not a method** but **it is an interface**.

```
public @interface RequiresApi {
   //......
}
```

Also it was introduced with the annotation support library **v.24.0.0**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had older version of annotation library, while migrating to androidx as following :

```
api 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
```

However after upgrading to latest stable version RequiresApi is able to resolve.

```
api 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
```

Imported as

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
```